# Multiple selection in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

Good night. I'm using cakephp 3.0 and I would really appreciate if could help me solving the follow issue:

I have a list of selections defined in this array:

```
$daysOfWeek = ['Monday' => 'Monday', 'Tuesday' => 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday' => 'Wednesday', 'Thursday' => 'Thursday', 'Friday' => 'Friday', 'Saturday' => 'Saturday', 'Sunday' => 'Sunday'];
```

In my ***add*** view, I have something like this in order to allow multiple days selection:

```
echo $this->Form->input('day_of_week', [
    'options' => $daysOfWeek,
    multiple' => 'checkbox']);
```

Doing this, cakephp was always saving me and empty value in the ***daysOfWeek*** field in my database, so I had to edit the model adding the next function:

```
public function beforeMarshal(CakeEvent $event, ArrayObject $data, ArrayObject $options)
{
    $data['day_of_week'] = json_encode($data['day_of_week']);
}
```

Now, the values of the multiple selections is saving as follows in the database:

```
["Saturday","Sunday"]
```

But If the user wants to edit the information of some entry of this table, the checkboxes of ***daysOfWeek*** never are selected. How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are missing `'` around `multiple`. use this : `'multiple' => 'checkbox'`.Also `$daysOfWeek` should be out of the array.

Comment: Thanks Mr. engineer, I already have the ' before multiple, but I don't understand how $daysOfWeek should be. Can you explain me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your response. Finally I solved the issue in the controller as follows:

```
public function edit($id = null)
{
    $event = $this->Events->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Categories', 'Playlists']
    ]);
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $event = $this->Events->patchEntity($event, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Events->save($event)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The event has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The event could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $categories = $this->Events->Categories->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $playlists = $this->Events->Playlists->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $daysOfWeek = ['Monday' => 'Monday', 'Tuesday' => 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday' => 'Wednesday', 'Thursday' => 'Thursday', 'Friday' => 'Friday', 'Saturday' => 'Saturday', 'Sunday' => 'Sunday'];
    $event->day_of_week = json_decode($event->day_of_week);
    $this->set(compact('event', 'categories', 'playlists', 'daysOfWeek'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['event']);
}
```

In the view is just the same thing:

```
echo $this->Form->input('day_of_week',array(
                'type' => 'select', 
                'multiple' => 'checkbox', 
                'options' => $daysOfWeek));
```

Answer (score 1):

You've missed `selected` property of dropdown. Please use this code :

```
$arr = array("Saturday","Sunday");
$this->Form->input('day_of_week',array(
                              'type' => 'select', 
                              'multiple' => true, 
                              'options' => $daysOfWeek,
                              'selected' => $arr));
```